# Making cookies in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, blazor

Im making own user login in Blazor. I would like to create cookies with user's data when user login succesfully. But Im getting error with using Response: " 'Response' does not contain a definition for 'Cookies' ". There is no right package to install while press 'ctrl + .'. Is there any other way to append cookie?

My code making cookies:

`

```
        HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie();
        userCookie.Name = "userId";
        userCookie.Value = user.Username;
        Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
```

//Account controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;
    public AccountController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }
    [HttpPost("register")]
    public ActionResult RegisterUser([FromBody] RegisterUserDto dto)
    {
        _accountService.RegisterUser(dto);
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost("login")]
    public ActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginDto dto)
    {
        _accountService.Login(dto);
        if (/*is logged*/)
        {
            return Ok("not logged");
        }
        return Ok("logged");
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Is this just an experiment? It is trivial for a user to change a cookie value and thus effectively become another user when you use unencrypted plain text like that.

Comment: It's just example to create cookie. How would you store data about logged user then?
In blazor it's not possible to use JWT.

Comment: JWT is possible in blazor. All web frameworks still have to speak HTTP.

Comment: If you are going to store a user identifier in the cookie it should be encrypted and verified on the server so that the user cannot modify it to a valid value.

Comment: When did you want to store or read your cookie? A SPA does only 1 Http request. Then it's on its own.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I wouldn't say that. There is no mention that this is strictly a single page application. It is common to have more than one page that each act as a SPA individually. Additionally, there are generally a lot of API calls going on, any of which may require AuthN/AuthZ via the cookie.

Comment: Still, there is a lot of info missing here. @metel: Blazor Serverside ort WebAssembly?  What does the Controller code look like?

Comment: @HenkHolterman WebAssembly, account controller code added in edit

Comment: And where do you (try to) set the cookies?